# Ansible: How can I 'set_fact' o to define a variable after running a condition

Tags: linux, ansible, conditional-statements, ansible-facts

I have a list `{{ users }}` of all users on a system, and I want to check if there is a specific file in their home directories, then define the new list of users when filename exist:

```yaml
- name: Get all users in system
  shell: |
  cat /etc/passwd | awk -F':' '{ print $1}'
  register: users

- set_fact:
    all_users: "{{ users.stdout_lines | list  }}"

- name: Check if file exists 
  file:
    path: /home/{{ item }}
    state: file
  register: file_status
  loop: "{{ all_users }}"

- set_fact:
    new_user_list: "get users from all_users that meet the previous conditions of file exist"
```

```yaml
- set_fact:
    new_user_list:  {{ all_users }}
    when: file_status.exist
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the module *getent* to read */etc/passwd*

```yaml
    - getent:
        database: passwd
```

Declare the list of all users

```yaml
  all_users: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
```

Use the module *stat* to test the files

```yaml
    - stat:
        path: "/home/{{ item }}"
      register: file_status
      loop: "{{ all_users }}"
```

Declare the list of new users who have the file

```yaml
  new_users: "{{ file_status.results|
                 selectattr('stat.exists')|
                 map(attribute='item') }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    all_users: "{{ getent_passwd.keys()|list }}"
    new_users: "{{ file_status.results|
                   selectattr('stat.exists')|
                   map(attribute='item') }}"

  tasks:

    - getent:
        database: passwd

    - stat:
        path: "/home/{{ item }}"
      register: file_status
      loop: "{{ all_users }}"

    - debug:
        var: new_users
```